# Поиск по ключевым словам в БД

Tags: php, foreach

Всем привет.
Помогите, пожалуйста.
Как правильно реализовать поиск в БД через PHP по ключевым словам.
Я имею 2 таблицы:

1. table_1 является словарем с 2 столбцами (id и keyword)
2. table_2 хранит в себе информацию, в частности в таблиц есть поле text.

Я понимаю, что мне необходимо в цикле обходить table_2['text'] проверяя наличие всех table_1['keyword'].
Я пробовал самостоятельно реализовать через foreach, но ничего не получилось.

Comment: Это делается одним запросом в БД. Примерно так `SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE text = (SELECT keyword FROM table_1)`

Answer (score 0):

Это делается одним запросом в БД. +1
Но если нужно на php :

```
$tabl1 = [
    '1' => 'keyword',
    '2' => 'ipsum',
    '3' => 'dolor',
    '4' => 'key'
];

$tabl2 = [
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua',
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua',
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua',
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua',
];

$size_tabl2 = count($tabl2) -1;

for($i = 0; $i <= $size_tabl2; $i++){

    for (reset($tabl1); ($key = key($tabl1)); next($tabl1))
    {
        if(strripos($tabl2[$i], $tabl1[$key])){
            echo "№ " . $i . " text : " . $tabl2[$i];
            echo "keyword : " . $tabl1[$key];
            echo "<br>";
        }

    }

}
```